# How generate frame with detected face from aws Kinesis real-time streaming video?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

I am working on Kinesis real-time streaming video POC.

I could able to stream video from android app to video-stream and called python boto3 api ('get_records') for face detection.

Face getting detected and getting response from api.

```
"InputInformation": {
            "KinesisVideo": {
                "StreamArn": "arn:aws:kinesisvideo:<video-stream>",
                "FragmentNumber": "913..",
                "ServerTimestamp": 1.5234201234E9,
                "ProducerTimestamp": 1.523420130123E9,
                "FrameOffsetInSeconds": 0.6769999861718424
            }
        },
        "StreamProcessorInformation": {
            "Status": "RUNNING"
        },
        "FaceSearchResponse": [{
            "DetectedFace": {
                "BoundingBox": {
                    "Height": 0.41025642,
                    "Width": 0.30769232,
                    "Left": 0.45673078,
                    "Top": 0.23397435
                },
                "Confidence": 99.99998, ........
```

Question:
How do I generate a frame by highlighting detected face from this data stream output (by referring video-stream data)?

I am not finding any example or document in aws reference page to create a frame and store it as jpeg image with face highlight.

Any help/pointer on example in java / python api to generate frame from video-stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the AWS Rekognition integration with Kinesis Video Streams, please checkout the [KinesisVideoRekognitionIntegrationExample](https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/examples/KinesisVideoRekognitionIntegrationExample.java#L41) published in the Consumer Parser library. This example shows how to ingest video file (which you can replace with real-time producer like [GStreamer sample application](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp#gstreamer-webcam-demo-application)), retrieve data, parse MKV, decode H264 frames using JCodec, integrate with Rekognition JSON output and draw bounding boxes on the face detected using JFrame.

Comment: Thanks @Babu-prasad

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated facility to modify the video data based on detected faces. You would need to write an application that:

- Retrieves the frame from Amazon Kinesis Video
- Retrieves the record from the Amazon Kinesis Stream generated by Amazon Rekognition Video
- Add your own rectangle to the frame (eg with ImageMagick or OpenCV)